Unity C# Raycast2D
Я хочу сделать движение пули прямую линию(как в ксго) и для это решил воспользоваться рейкастом. Но правда не понимаю как мне сделать так, чтобы моя пуля летела ровно по направлению рейкаста. Буду очень благодарен помощи!
public class ZombieBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float _distance = 30f; // максимальное расстояние для рейкаста
    private int _damage = 10;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, _distance);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            HandlePlayerCollision(hit);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = hit.point;
        }
    }

    private void HandlePlayerCollision(RaycastHit2D hit)
    {
        if (hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out Player player))
        {
            player.TakeDamage(_damage);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

